# Loop through css possible?

Tags: html, css

I have used the same CSS code loads of times but just giving it different names. So basically I am calling the same CSS over and over but named differently. I feel like I should loop through it instead. Any ideas?

```
#block1{display:block; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;}
#block1.a{display:none; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;}

#block2{display:block; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;}
#block2.a{display:none; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;}

#block3{display:block; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;}
#block3.a{display:none; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;}

#block4{display:block; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;}
#block4.a{display:none; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;}

#block5{display:block; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;}
#block5.a{display:none; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;}
```

Then in the HTML I do this:

```
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('block1').setAttribute('class', '');"> 
        <b><abbr title="Reports showing all cases with various display options."><span style='color:black;'>Current Status Reports</b></span></button><br>
            <div id="block1" class="a">
                <a href="javascript:GenerateReport( 'https://www.kerrys.com/oecgi.exe/dm_currentstatus_crprocess');">Current Status Report With Legal Process</a><br>
                <a href="javascript:GenerateReport( 'https://www.kerrys.com/oecgi.exe/dm_currentstatus');">Current Status Report</a><br>
                <a href="javascript:GenerateReport( 'https://www.kerrys.com/oecgi.exe/dm_currentstatus_last_response');">Current Status Report With Last Response</a><br>
                <a href="javascript:GenerateReport( 'https://www.kerrys.com/oecgi.exe/dm_currentstatus_last_receipt');">Current Status Report With Last Receipt</a><br>
                <a href="javascript:GenerateReport( 'https://www.kerrys.com/oecgi.exe/dm_currentstatus_last_response_plantiff');">Current Status Report With Last Response and Plaintiff</a><br>
                <a href="javascript:GenerateReport( 'https://www.skerrys.com/oecgi.exe/dm_currentstatus_trxdte');">Current Status Report by Date Transferred</a><br>
                <button onclick="document.getElementById('block1').setAttribute('class', 'a');"><b>Hide -</b></button>
            </div>


        <button onclick="document.getElementById('block2').setAttribute('class', '');"> <b><abbr title="Reports showing current new business & demand letters sent to debtors.">New Business & Letters Before Action</b></button><br>
            <div id="block2" class="a">
                <a href="javascript:GenerateReport( 'https://www.kerrys.com/oecgi.exe/DM_NewBusiness');">New Business This Period</a><br>
                <a href="javascript:GenerateReport( 'https://www.kerrys.com/oecgi.exe/DM_LBASent');">Letter Before Action Sent</a><br>
                <a href="javascript:GenerateReport( 'https://www.kerrys.com/oecgi.exe/DM_CasesAwaitingInstructions_Issue');">Cases Awaiting Instructions to Issue</a><br>
                <button onclick="document.getElementById('block2').setAttribute('class', 'a');"><b>Hide -</b></button>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can use commas in the specifier, e.g. `block1, block1.a, block2, block2.a, ... { ... }`

Comment: @Jon That should be an answer.

Comment: Or use a class instead of ID

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, you could use the css attribute selector `^=`, that is sort of a **starts with** selector:

```
[id^="block"] {
    /* your style */
}

[id^="block"].a {
    /* your style */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. in your case it's almost trivial.

```
#block1, #block2, (etc) {
    //Your style here
}
```

Looking at your existing CSS, I'm not sure it's doing what you think it is. `#block1.a` isn't setting the style on the 'a' elements within the html, it's setting it on the same element, the .a associates it with the class, defined by your `class="a"` attribute.

Although you're far better off setting a class for your styles, and using that, such as

```
div.a { //style for `div class="a"` elements
}
div.a a { // style for 'a' elements within those divs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your current code you can change it to:

```
#block1, #block2, #block3, #block4, #block5 {
    display:block; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;
}

#block1.a, #block2.a, #block3.a, #block4.a, #block5.a {
    display:none; background-color:#FFFFFF ; color:black; padding:1px; margin:5px;
}
```

But it may be better to just have a `block` class:

```
.block { display:block; ... }
.block.a { display:none; ... }
```